# i am unable to start the application from cloud foundry cli

Tags: ibm-cloud

i am getting error bits not uploaded even though i am able to upload the app from cf cli.
check the log of commands executed below.
Where is the error?
i followed all steps as shown in dw001 video correctly.

```
F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>
F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cd dir
The system cannot find the path specified.

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>dir
 Volume in drive F is Comp Stuff
 Volume Serial Number is 5635-6A95

 Directory of F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1

01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          .
01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          ..
01-12-2015  17:40                13 .cfignore
01-12-2015  17:40             7,171 .jshintrc
01-12-2015  17:40               429 .project
01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          .settings
01-12-2015  17:40             9,873 app.js
01-12-2015  17:40               176 manifest.yml
01-12-2015  17:40               429 package.json
01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          public
01-12-2015  17:40               445 README.md
01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          routes
01-12-2015  23:12    <DIR>          views
               7 File(s)         18,536 bytes
               6 Dir(s)   1,294,770,176 bytes free

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf push BI-MyFirstDeploy-3 -c "node app.js" -m 128M --no-manifest
Updating app BI-MyFirstDeploy-3 in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK

Creating route bi-myfirstdeploy-3.mybluemix.net...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken: bi-myfirstdeploy-3

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf push testappl -c "node app.js" -m 128M --no-manifest
Creating app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK

Creating route testappl.mybluemix.net...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken: testappl

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf bs testappl testappl1-cloudantNoSQLDB
Binding service testappl1-cloudantNoSQLDB to app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK
TIP: Use 'cf restage testappl' to ensure your env variable changes take effect

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf start testappl
Starting app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 150001, message: The app package is invalid: bits have not been uploaded

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf cs cloudantNoSQLDB Shared testservice1
Creating service instance testservice1 in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK

Attention: The plan `Shared` of service `cloudantNoSQLDB` is not free.  The instance `testservice1` will incur a cost.  Contact your administrator if
you think this is in error.


F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf bs testappl testservice1
FAILED
App testappl not found

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf push testappl -c "node app.js" -m 128M --no-manifest
Creating app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK

Creating route testappl.mybluemix.net...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken: testappl

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf bs testappl testservice1
Binding service testservice1 to app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
OK
TIP: Use 'cf restage testappl' to ensure your env variable changes take effect

F:\IBM BLUEMIX\DW001\testappl1>cf start testappl
Starting app testappl in org pr00330912@techmahindra.com / space Test1 as pr00330912@techmahindra.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 150001, message: The app package is invalid: bits have not been uploaded
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server error, status code: 400, error code: 210003, message: The host is taken:**

The host name (application name by default) is already taken by another user or org. Pick a unique name. For example:

`cf push testappl_GOWTHI -c "node app.js" -m 128M --no-manifest`